# What is Enum.HasFlag supposed to return?

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have the enum:

```
[Flags]
enum Editions
{
    Educational,
    Basic,
    Pro,
    Ultra
}
```

why do I get this behavior?

```
var x = Editions.Basic;
var y = Editions.Educational;
var test =x.HasFlag(y); // why is this true!?
// and!!!
var test2 = y.HasFlag(x); // this is false!
```

Comment: The `Flags` attribute is supposed to be used with enumerations where each value corresponds to a separate bit. The way you're using it doesn't really make sense, so there will be more than just `HasFlag` that will give confusing results.

Comment: [MSDN FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you how to use the attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using the `[Flags]` attribute you should explicitly map the enum values to integer that contain non overlapping bit patterns. That is, each enum value should be mapped to a power of two:

```
[Flags]
enum Editions
{
    Educational = 1,
    Basic = 2,
    Pro = 4,
    Ultra = 8
}
```

Without the explicit numbering, `Educational` will be mapped to 0 and `Basic` to 1.

`Enum.HasFlags` checks if the bit field or bit fields that are set in the parameter are also all set in the tested enum. In your case, `x` is 1 and `y` is 0. That means that `x` contains all of the bits set in `0` (that is no bits at all). However `0` does not contain the bits set in `1` when testing the other way around.

Comment: This suggests that `Editions.Educational | Editions.Basic` makes sense. I think it's more likely that these enum values shouldn't be flags, and the `Flags` attribute should be removed as well.

Answer (score 7):

It returns true because you implemented `Editions` incorrectly. You must explicitly set the values when you use the `[Flags]` attribute.

```
[Flags]
enum Editions
{                         //binary format
    Educational = 1 << 0, // 0001
    Basic  = 1 << 1,      // 0010
    Pro  = 1 << 2,        // 0100
    Ultra  = 1 << 3       // 1000
}
```

If you do not assign numbers it will auto assign them starting at 0 going up by 1 for each option after that (this is standard `enum` behavior, adding the `[Flags]` attribute does not change this behavior)

```
[Flags]
enum Editions
{                    //binary format
    Educational = 0, // 0000
    Basic  = 1,      // 0001
    Pro  = 2,        // 0010
    Ultra  = 3       // 0011
}
```

So the two tests you did was: `0001` has the flag `0000` set (which is true, you are not testing for any flags) and `0000` has the flag `0001` set (which is defiantly false)

---

However looking at your names I doubt you should be using `[Flags]` at all because I doubt whatever you are doing can be `Basic` and be `Pro` at the same time. If you are trying to use flags to make testing enum values easier just use a switch statement instead

```
Editions edition = GetEdition();

switch(edition)
{
    case Editions.Basic:
         DoSomthingSpecialForBasic();
         break;

    case Editions.Pro:
    case Editions.Ultra:
        DoSomthingSpecialForProAndUltra();
        break;

    //Does not do anything if Editions.Educational
}
```